# How to use the object from a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I am using a linked list for an assignment, and I am confused about something. We have to create another class for a phonebook, that takes in the name and number, and then store it in a linkedlist, and I got most of it figured out. Until I started to try and get the person object out of the linked list so I can run the methods I wrote for the my person object, like the getters and setters and such. But when I pull it back out of the linked list, it is just an object and not a person I put in, How do you get the object back out so that I can use it as the object I put in.
Thanks

Ok, sorry about adding it in the comments. 
This is the test i have tried so far,
The person class has a print method, but I forgot about assigning the type with the

```
public static void main(String[] args) {      
    LinkedList phonedir = new LinkedList();
    person one = new person("John", "Doe", "1234567890");
    phonedir.add(one);
    Object two = phonedir.get(0);
    two.print();
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you have defined the list using new LinkedList<Object> but you need to show us some code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LinkedList<person>` so that the compiler knows that what you get out is a `person`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<person> phonedir = new LinkedList<person>(); 
    person one = new person("John", "Doe", "1234567890"); 
    phonedir.add(one); 
    person two = phonedir.get(0); 
    two.print(); 
}
```

Also, it should be `Person`. Class names in Java should begin with capitals!

Comment: Ok, thanks. And I forget what should be caps and not. Is it just classes that are caps, or some methods caps too?

Comment: Classes should be capitalized. Methods and variables should be `camelCase`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SaveRetrieveObjects {
    List<Item>  objs        = new LinkedList<Item>();
    File        fileName    = new File("objects.sav");

public SaveRetrieveObjects() {
    createItems();
    showItems();
    serializeObjs(objs, fileName);
    objs = deserializeObjs(objs, fileName);
    showItems();
    System.out.println("Vale!");
}

private void createItems() {
    Item oneObject = new Item();
    oneObject.setId("Citric-45");
    oneObject.setDesc("orange");
    oneObject.setCost(12345.67);
    oneObject.setQty(67);
    oneObject.setBool(true);
    oneObject.setColor(Color.orange);
    objs.add(oneObject);

    oneObject = new Item();
    oneObject.setId("Mobil-12");
    oneObject.setDesc("car");
    oneObject.setCost(67890.12);
    oneObject.setQty(2);
    oneObject.setBool(true);
    oneObject.setColor(new Color(1, 2, 3));
    objs.add(oneObject);
}

private void showItems() {
    Item itm;
    for (int j = 0; j < objs.size(); j++) {
        itm = objs.get(j);
        System.out.println("Item " + (j + 1) + " Contents:");
        System.out.print("\t" + itm.getId());
        System.out.print("\t" + itm.getDesc());
        System.out.print("\t" + itm.getCost());
        System.out.print("\t\t" + itm.getQty());
        System.out.println("\t" + itm.isBool());
        System.out.println("\t" + itm.getColor());
    }
     System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
}

private void serializeObjs(List<Item> objs, File file) {
    System.out.println("Serialization process started");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(objs);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nSerialization ended successfully");
    System.out.println("Checkout your specified output file");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<Item> deserializeObjs(List<Item> objs, File file) {
    objs.clear();
    System.out.println("Deserialization process started");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        objs.addAll((Collection<? extends Item>) ois.readObject());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Deserialization process ended");
    return objs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SaveRetrieveObjects();
        }
    });
}
}

class Item implements Serializable {
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

private String                      id;
private String                      desc;
private double                      cost;
private int                             qty;
private boolean                     bool;
private Color                           color;

public Item() {
    id = "";
    desc = "";
    cost = 0;
    qty = 0;
    bool = false;
    color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
}

public Item(String id, String desc, double cost, int qty, boolean bool, Color color) {
    this.id = id;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.bool = bool;
    this.color = color;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String itemID) {
    this.id = itemID;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public double getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(double cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setQty(int quantity) {
    this.qty = quantity;
}

public boolean isBool() {
    return bool;
}

public void setBool(boolean bool) {
    this.bool = bool;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}
}
```

Here is a full example on "How to use Objects from a Linked List".
Use of Objects in a LinkedList or ArrayList:
 Steps:
 * -Create Class Item implements Serializable.
 * -Create the Item Objects.
 * -Add them to an ArrayList or LinkedList. These, ArrayList or LinkedList, do
 not need to be serializable! Only the Item class needs to implement
 serializable.
 * -Using streams write and retrieve the objects to and from file chosen.
 Hope this helps as has done for others. Vale!

Comment: Forgot to include for the above program: class SaveRetrieveObjects the following imports: java.awt.Color; java.io.*; java.util.*; and you are all set! Again: Vale!